# how to convert string into date? JAVA

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have this string: 7 -Jun- 2014.
I want to convert to java.utils.Date;

I use this Code

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";

        try {

            Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println(date);
            System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but I get this exception :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "7-Jun-2013"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at ma.abcsolution.util.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: You gave the date to it in the format of `d-MMM-yyyy` for a SimpleDateFormat of `dd/MM/yyyy`, obviously it crashes. Look at how to create date string for date format:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: the dateformat that you have provided for SimpleDateFormat and your search string don't match. change you date format to dd-MMM-YYYY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SimpleDateFormatter you can convert from date string to date and date to date String

```
public final class DateUtil {

    private static final String DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MMM-yyyy";

    private DateUtil() {
    }

    public static final String formatDate(final Date date, final String dateFormat) {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
        return format.format(date);
    }

    public static final Date formatDate(final String date) throws ParseException {
        return formatDate(date, DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT);
    }

    public static final Date formatDate(final String date, final String dateFormat) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        return format.parse(date);
    }
}
```

Whenever you are going yo format date please verify the format you are using
In your case you used `dd/MM/yyyy` but date you used in format `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

the `SimpleDateFormat` look at the given string like it you tell it to, so in your example it look for a string with 2 chars for days, followed by a '/' sign and then 2 chars for month and so on

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

to format the date. You used the wrong format with the `/` signs.

See also:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy").parse("7-Jun-2014");
```

Comment: i get this exception :
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "7-Jun-2014"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at ma.abcsolution.util.Test.main(Test.java:10)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. It is simple.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateTime {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";

        Date date=new Date(dateInString);

        System.out.println(ft.format(date));


    }
}
```